# Get message id after using /sendMail API

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am using Microsoft Graph to authorize our app and send mail with authenticated details:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail
```

Everything works well but it only returns `HTTP Status Code 202` without the message's `id`.

Is there a way to get the `id` of the the sent message?

Answer (score 0):

After sending the message, you can find the message in the Send Items folder using [`/mailfolders/SentItems/messages`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/mailfolder_list_messages). You can apply a `$filter` to limit the results to only the message in question.

There isn't however a way to get the `id` itself. To get around this you can use [extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview) to add your own unique id to the message.

Using your own ID allows you to instantly `$filter` out everything except the exact message you are looking for. To do this you first construct a [draft message](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_messages). You then add your custom data and [send the draft message](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_send).